# nuget.org - how to prevent unlisted package from being downloaded when Update-Package is being used

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, manage-nuget-packages

I have created a package on Nuget.org.
However, when doing one of the first releases, I have used set an incorrect assembly version format - which is used as the package version.

Let's say that the version was 1.0.180305.0 (build date)
However, I do not want to use this format, I want a simpler thing with Major.Minor.BuildNumber format, i.e. 1.0.10, 1.0.11, 1.0.12 etc, where I increment Major and Minor manually and the Build number incremented automatically.

I have unlisted the 1.0.180305.0 version, so that it does not appear anywhere.

This works all OK, however when using Update-Package [PackageName] in Package Manager Console, it automatically gets the 1.0.180305.0 - even though its unlisted - because the version number is 'larger'.

How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

> nuget.org - how to prevent unlisted package from being downloaded when Update-Package is being used

This is a known issue about Package Manager Console in Visual Studio not filtering out unlisted packages on Update-Package commands.

The current **workaround** is using the command line: `Uninstall-Package [-Id]` and then `Install-Package [-Id]`

Issue 4553: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4553

Besides, this issue was fixed at Visual Studio 2017 15.6.0 preview3 (Current version is 15.7.3), I test it in my side with Visual Studio 2017 15.6.6, this issue no longer occurs. So you can also update Visual Studio to resolve this issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It does indeed. I didnt think it was a VS bug.

Comment: Actually, this still does not work in VS 15.7.4, the bug was not fixed (or not properly)